# Is there a simple way to map the row number of the record in the CSV file to a POCO?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have a process that imports many CSV files with different definitions and converts them into a corresponding number of discrete POCO types based on various logic. In order to better troubleshoot problems, I now need to record the number of the row on the POCOs themselves. As such I've created a base class for all my POCOs with a single property to handle this.

As per [this discussion](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/discussions/1689#discussioncomment-336191) it's possible to map the row/line number of a CSV file record to a POCO by constructing a [`ClassMap`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/ClassMap%601.cs). However I'm currently using the [`IndexAttribute`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/Attributes/IndexAttribute.cs) applied to each property in my POCO to perform the mapping. Since I have many POCOs, and mapping is currently working perfectly, I would prefer to not have to create `ClassMap`s for every POCO (not only is it more complex and IMO trickier to maintain, it's also more effort).

Is there a simple alternative, preferably using an attribute, to achieve row/line number => POCO property mapping? I looked through the attributes in the CSVHelper repo but didn't see anything that looks relevant.

Comment: Did you consider a base class for the poco's that has the line index?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `TypeConverter` attribute.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        HasHeaderRecord = false,
        MissingFieldFound = null
    };
    
    using (var reader = new StringReader("1,One\n2,Two"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().Dump();
    }
}

public class Foo 
{
    [Index(0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Index(1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [TypeConverter(typeof(RowNumberConverter))]
    public int RowNumber { get; set; }
}

public class RowNumberConverter : DefaultTypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        return row.Context.Parser.Row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and this is what worked for me :

```
private class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [LineNumber]
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }
}

private class LineNumber : Attribute, IMemberMapper, IParameterMapper
{
    public void ApplyTo(MemberMap memberMap)
    {
        memberMap.Data.ReadingConvertExpression = (ConvertFromStringArgs args) => args.Row.Parser.Row;
    }

    public void ApplyTo(ParameterMap parameterMap)
    {
    }
}
```

For more informations, check it [here](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/discussions/1689#discussioncomment-3004799)

Answer (score 1):

If you use [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) then you can simply do like this :

```
Map(m => m.LineNumber).Convert(row => row.Context.Row);
```

A full example will be like below:

```
void Main()
{
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
{
    writer.WriteLine("Id,Name");
    writer.WriteLine("1,one");
    writer.WriteLine("2,two");
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    
    csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<TestMap>();
    csv.GetRecords<Test>().ToList().Dump();
}
}

public class Test
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int RowNumber { get; set; }
}

public sealed class TestMap : ClassMap<Test>
{
  public TestMap()
  {
     Map(m => m.Id);
     Map(m => m.Name);
     Map(m => m.RowNumber).Convert(row => row.Context.Row);
  }
}
```

For the discussion and more information you can have look [here](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/845).